# A problem in the existence of a sequence from $\Bbb Q$ to $\Bbb R$

Tags: calculus

For every $x$ belonging to the interval $[1,2]$, is it possible to define a sequence of rational numbers which is convergent to the logarithm with base $2$ of $x$? I tried to find a specific form for this sequence without success, in particular I don’t know  if it exists.

Comment: Just use the continued fraction of $\log_2(x)$ to create a sequence of rational numbers (quickly) converging to $\log_2(x)$

Comment: @molarmass, yours must be one of the most useless edits ever performed on MSE. Please don't do it again.

Comment: @Rohan, I have asked you to stop editing posts! Are you playing games here?

Comment: The word you want is "sequence" (the English word for "sucesión").

Comment: @Alex M. I have not edited any post after that edit. No fault of mine.

Comment: @AlexM. It looks to me like the edit by molarmass was probably written before Rohan's edit, but approved after it had been rendered obsolete by Rohan's edit? That would be a bug in the system, not any particular person making a bad edit.

Comment: Hi Yildiz, I saw your meta post and there is absolutely nothing wrong with [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/301460/2751) or your other similar question. BTW on PhysicsOverflow we dont have such an issue with unjustified downvotes and high-level technical theoretical physics questions are welcome, we dont call them homework  ... Best wishes

Answer (score 1):

Given an irrational number $x \in [1,2]$, consider the decimal expansion of $\log_2(x) \in [0, 1]$

Let $a_n$ be the the truncation of $\log_2(x)$ up to $n$-th digit.

that is $a_n = \frac{\lfloor 10^n\log_2(x) \rfloor}{10^n}$

If we want faster convergence rate, we can even choose the sequence $b_n = \frac{\lfloor 10^{2^n}\log_2(x) \rfloor}{10^{2^n}}$ which is a subsequence of the previous sequence.